# Where are the Crystal Report .Net assemblies placed when installing the redistribution package?

Tags: crystal-reports

Running any of the [Crystal Reports 10.5 redistributables](https://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=56787567) (`CRRedist2008_x86.msi`, `CRRedist2008_x64.msi` or `CRRedist2008_ia64.ms`) is supposed to, according to the `Crystal_Runtime2008.txt` file, deploy the following files:

```
CRVsPackageLib.dll
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Design.dll
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
CrystalDecisions.Data.AdoDotNetInterop.dll
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Report.dll
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework.dll
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore.dll
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.PluginManager.dll
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Viewing.ReportSource.dll
CrystalDecisions.Keycode.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonControls.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonObjectModel.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ObjectFactory.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.dll
CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll
CrystalDecisions.Web.dll
CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.dll
```

But I am unable to find these anywhere on the PC. Does anyone know what location they're installed to? All the other DLLs listed in the .txt file appear in

`c:\Program Files\Business Objects\Common\2.8\bin`

Comment: What is the problem by the way? Is the redist not installing properly?

Comment: I'm not sure..I'm trying to run an application with only VS 2010 + CR redist package and it's crashing not being able to find assemblies.

Comment: Do you realize that the CR 10.5 is the crystal reports that comes with VS 2008? Does 2010 come with another version?

Comment: It doesn't come with 2010 at all. There was a lot of back-and-forth on this until the final word came from SAP in December (http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/weblogs?blog=/pub/wlg/14514)

Comment: In the end, I was able to use the CR 2008 SP2 redist package (http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=56787567), extract the two assemblies from the GAC I needed, and all was well.

Comment: This seems to still be a problem with SAP/crystal installers 2012, version 14.  I am posting [here](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3175725) about my adventures.  I found this thread having had to retrace your steps, looking for info on how to copy stuff out of the assembly.  Which if you use command prompt, for me, is, cd \windows\assembly\gac_misl and start looking.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

the [GAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz.aspx)

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4, the default location for the
>   global assembly cache is %windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly. In earlier
>   versions of the .NET Framework, the default location is
>   %windir%\assembly

Comment: They are there indeed..now to figure out why the application refuses to recognize their presence :)

Comment: In case anyone is wondering how to extract them from the GAC, there is a nice, simple method here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714907/how-to-extract-an-assembly-from-the-gac/714929#714929

Comment: Did you ever find out why the application wouldn't load them from the GAC?

Answer (score 4):

Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) on a running version of the app, such as your dev machine, to see from where all of its DLLs are loaded.

**EDIT:**

Process Explorer is a great way to find out what DLLs are loaded into any Windows process be it from the GAC or any other location. This method (using ProcEx) is general, but IMO useful in many scenarios. ProcEx would indeed show you that a program's Crystal Redist was being loaded from the GAC.

**SUGGESTED EDIT:**

Find .NET DLLs in this way:

1. Find your task in the process list of Process Explorer
2. Double click on the task to show Task Properties
3. At .NET Assemblies tab open plus(+) sign, display App Domain etc. (only .NET processes will have this tab. Non.NET process will not have the tab at all)

Comment: Mr Paul Sasik please you re edit your answer in order to i can up vote it,

Comment: i founded DLL references in Process Explorer sotfware by this way : 1-Find My Task ,2-Double Click on Task for Showed Task Properties , At .NET Assemblies tab , left side of screen , open Plus(+) sign, display App Domain that is true, 
also thanks your time Mr Paul Sasik , sorry for last my judgement ,thank you

Comment: @AliSarshogh: Again, thank you for the reconsideration. Please find your comment added into the answer. Great idea to share that information in the answer!