# Re-register DLL after Extract DLL problem

Tags: .net, dll, assemblies, gac

I have follow the guide to get DLL from GAC from [How to extract an assembly from the GAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714907/how-to-extract-an-assembly-from-the-gac)

below is the step that I have done:

1. Run regsvr32 /u C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\shfusion.dll
2. shfusion.dll is an explorer extension DLL that gives a distinct look to the GAC folder. Unregistering this file will remove the assembly cache viewer and the GAC folder will be then visible as any normal folder in explorer.
3. Open “%windir%\assembly\GAC_MSIL”.
4. Browse to your DLL folder into the deep to find your DLL.
5. Copy the DLL somewhere on your hard disk and refer it from there in your project
6. Run "regsvr32 /i %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<.NET version directory> \shfusion.dll" to re-register the shfusion.dll file and regain the original distinct view of the GAC.

As I do step 6, I found the following warning message:

"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\shfusion.dll was loaded, but the DllInstall entry point was not found.

This file can not be registered."

How can I re-register DLL?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `/i`

```
"regsvr32 %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<.NET version directory> \shfusion.dll"
```

That worked for me.

You might also want to use the `shfusion.dll` in the `Framework64` folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you system is 64 BIT then you must try from framework 64. Here it is.

> regsvr32 %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\shfusion.dll