# Is it possible to xcopy deploy the Microsoft ReportViewer web control?

Tags: deployment, reporting-services

I'm trying to setup Microsoft reporting on a shared hosted server. I've set up the web.config files with the necessary entries and uploaded the assemblies `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll` and `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll` as well as the file Microsoft.ReportViewer.xml via FTP.

The site loads OK, but when I try to load a report a get a missing reference to `Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll`. If I can get a hold of a copy of this dll, can I expect the report view to work? If so, what's the best way to get a copy? Or should I start trying to cajole the server administrator to run ReportViewer.exe?

This project is using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the answer is yes. I had never extracted a file from the GAC before, but it was pretty easy by following the command line method described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714907/how-to-extract-an-assembly-from-the-gac). Once the correct version of Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll was extracted from the GAC on my development machine and uploaded to the site, the reports started working.

Comment: Rather than extracting these from the GAC, it may be better to add the [NuGet package for Microsoft.ReportViewer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportViewer/) to your VS solution.

Comment: Note: That Nuget package is unofficial and unsupported