# Tridion 2011 FxCop indirectly-referenced assembly

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am having an issue with analyzing my event system code with FxCop. When I run FxCop against my assembly I two messages

One reads

> The following indirectly-referenced assembly could not be found. This assembly is not required for analysis, however, without it, analysis results could be incomplete. This assembly was referenced by Tridion.ContentManager.dll.
>
> **Tridion.ContentManager.Data, Version=6.1.0.996, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b**

The other reads

> The following indirectly-referenced assembly could not be found. This assembly is not required for analysis, however, without it, analysis results could be incomplete. This assembly was referenced by Tridion.ContentManager.dll.
>
> **Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.cm_sys, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=360aac4d3354074b**

For each message I am asked to provide the location of the assembly in bold.

I have looked for the Tridion.ContentManager.Data assembly where I retrieved all the other Tridion assemblies but it isn't there.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will find this two assembly in the windows gac (global assembly cache).
  %WINDIR%\assembly\GAC_MSIL\

Comment: Thanks! The following two links gave me a guide on how to actually get the dll out of the GAC. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714907/how-to-extract-an-assembly-from-the-gac http://blogs.msdn.com/b/akukreja/archive/2008/05/23/get-dll-out-of-the-gac.aspx