# Telerik.WebControls assembly missing

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I'm moving some legacy sites built using the classic ASP.NET (i.e. non AJAX) Telerik RadControls. I'm running into the issue that it can't find the Telerik.WebControls dll.

It runs on the server it is currently on, even though I can't find that DLL anywhere on that server. Could it be installed in some other way or does anyone know where I can find this legacy assembly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check in the Global Assembly Cache on the server. It's possible that they installed it globally for all applications.

The location would likely be C:\Windows\assembly for an older version of .NET (pre 4.0)

If you find it there, then that means it was installed globally. It's likely sitting somewhere on the server and you could potentially do a search on the entire file system.

I found this post which also talks about extracting a DLL from the GAC [How to extract an assembly from the GAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714907/how-to-extract-an-assembly-from-the-gac)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I found that article you linked and I can find in the GAC the controls that I believe are in that assembly (i.e. RadCalendar.Net2.dll), but I installed them in the GAC on the new server and it is still looking for Telerik.WebControls.dll.

Comment: Actually, this turned out to be correct. Placing those individual files in the site worked.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. To put the files in the GAC you have to run the gacutil in order to get them registered correctly. If you just put them in there, by copying them, it may not always work. Permissions in newer versions of Windows is kind of odd and you sometimes have to do Run as Administrator for it to work properly.